# Can you still use C++ in Xcode?

Tags: c++, xcode, macos

I want to learn C++ on my Mac computer. A lot of forums recommend using Xcode, but when I downloaded it I realized that it only has options for Swift or Objective-C. Is there still a way to use C++ in Xcode?

Comment: It's there somewhere. You may need to download C++ tools separately through settings, I don't remember exactly.

Comment: Why don't you search for it on the web?

Comment: yes. You can add .cpp files to any project, although starting a "console application" project is the easiest way.

Answer (score 0):

The parts of a problem that interact with system APIs for making an app have to be Swift or Objective-C. (As such, the project templates that give you the bare skeleton of an app to get started with are only Swift and ObjC.)

However, an Objective-C app can use C++ internally. Just create `.mm` files instead of `.m` (or rename the ones you have from the project template) so that the compiler knows you're writing Objective-C++. Then you can write ObjC classes that create C++ objects or call into C++ libraries, write C++ classes or templates that store pointers to ObjC objects, etc.

Comment: Hmmm... I think your answer could be improved, since Xcode includes the option to create CLI apps with C, C++; it's also possible to include C, C++ within an Obj-C `.m` class file.